# Comics about sorcerer that is an heir to a kingdom on another plane

Tags: story-identification, comics

The main protagonist is a male sorcerer and son of a king of some strange kingdom not on earth - it's full of monsters and probably on another plane. The story starts with him and his mother living on earth, doing underworld business involving magic and then being called to be an heir of said kingdom. 
The comics art was very colorful and detailed, often showing hundreds of creatures/demons in wide, whole page shots.

> I think the story ended when the protagonist battled his monstrous half-brother over the kingdom.

EDIT: It was a paper comics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is **[Maestros](https://imagecomics.com/comics/series/maestros)** by Steve Skroce, published by Image comics. It is basically a much gorier version of *Doctor Strange*. From Image's website:

> The Maestro and his entire royal family have been murdered. Now, his banished son from Earth will inherit the Wizard King's throne along with a spell that turns its user into GOD. With enemies everywhere, will this Orlando-born millennial be able to keep his new magic kingdom?

It was originally published in 7 issues and has since been collected in a trade paperback (see cover below).

[image]